# vim の環境を移すことは出来ますか？

Tags: vim

Linuxやwsl2上等、複数の環境でvimを使っているのですが、
プラグインがうまく入らない環境があったりして難儀しています。
プラグインを含めたvimの環境をごそっと他のマシンに移す方法はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: 環境を移すことは可能ですが、「プラグインがうまく入らない」問題が解決するとは限りません。純粋に環境の移行を質問するのであれば「うまく入らない」の話は必要無いはずで、質問内容を見直してみてください。

Comment: かしこまりました。
この状況で質問内容を変更するのが適切なのか判らないので、
以降留意したく思います。

Answer (score 2):

基本的には~/.vim/をまるごとコピーすればよいです
ただ中には
・その環境に沿ったコンパイル済みの実行ファイルが必要(例:vimproc)
・JavaScript, Python, Rubyを始めとする外部プログラムと連携している
といったプラグインがあるので、それらは別途インストールが必要です

このあたりをどこまで簡単に行えるか?はプラグライン・マネージャー次第です

私の場合は、プラグイン・マネージャーは使わず~/.vim/packで管理しています
そのうえで、上記のがイププログラムなど必要な部分は、最初に行ったときにの作業をそのまま残して、シェル・スクリプトにしています

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
それぞれの~/.vim を確認してみたのですが、.vimが存在しない環境があったりして、
それぞれの環境を構築する際の私のやり方がそもそもバラバラだったのだと思います。今すぐ対応というのは一旦諦めて、
ご提示のように、作業内容をシェル・スクリプトにして残すようにしたいと思います。